# With Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, how can I get the value of a variable displayed on a webpage and not the memory address of the variable?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to display a list of registered website users and their user roles. User data is stored on one table and it's joined to another table with the indexed users and their roles (e.g. ROLE_DEFAULT_USER, ROLE_DEVELOPER, ROLE_ADMIN)

But in the column for Role, I'm getting what looks like a memory address.

[image]

When the List of Roles for each User is added to its UserDto I can see the names of the roles.

[image]

I'm using

xmlns:th=*"http://www.thymeleaf.org"*

The html code for displaying the table row is

```
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td><span th:text="${user?.name}"> name </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${user?.email}"> email </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${user?.businessName}"> business name </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${user?.roles}"> role </span></td> 
             <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
```

I tried <**td** th:text=*"${user.roles.name}"*>Roles</**td**>

But that throws this error "Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag' - maybe not public or not valid?"

The both the UserDto and User classes have

```
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
```

The mapping in the AuthController is

```
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model){
        List<UserDto> users = userServiceImpl.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "users";
    }
```

The UserServiceImpl has

```
    @Override
    public List<UserDto> findAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream()
                .map((user) -> mapToUserDto(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private UserDto mapToUserDto(User user) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

        userDto.setName(user.getName());
        userDto.setOrganization(user.getOrganization());
        userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userDto.setBusinessName(user.getBusinessName());
        userDto.setPhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber());
        userDto.setPostCode(user.getPostCode());
        userDto.setAddress(user.getAddress());
        userDto.setUsagePurpose(user.getUsagePurpose());
        userDto.setRoles(user.getRoles());

        return userDto;
    }
```

Comment: `roles` is a collection, so Thymeleaf will call `toString`. What you want it to iterate over the roles as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm trying to iterate over user.roles as well with #lists.contains. I need to find if a user is a developer or an admin. But th:if="${#lists.contains(user.roles, 'ROLE_ADMIN')}">User admin</span> is returning nothing.

Comment: Ofcourse not it is a `List<Role>` not a `LIst<String>` so the `contains` will not match.

Comment: What do you think `th:each` is doing... Right iterating over a list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class `Role` you should implement (override) the `toString()` method and return the `name` field.

**Background:** if the `toString()` method is not implemented for a particular class Java will use the `toString()` method implementation of the Object class which just returns the internal name of the instance:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

This is what you currently see on the front-end.

Additionally you can implement the toString() method in the UserDto class to get a pretty output of the collection of roles. Instead of default one with square brackets: [ROLE_DEFAULT_USER, ROLE_DEVELOPER]

Comment: Okay - that seems to be the path to fixing this problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return this.name;
}
```

to the Role.java did the trick. Though the output is surrounded by square brackets like so

[ROLE_DEFAULT_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]

Comment: That didn't do the trick it now only shows the output of the list `toString` method. You really should iterate over the nested list and display the results, not rely on `toString` to show someting in your frontend.

Comment: Yes - I understand I need and want to go through this nested list and pull out the values of each element. But so far I haven't been able to figure that out. To wit I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76554007/with-thymeleaf-whats-the-syntax-to-find-an-item-in-a-joined-list-using-lists

Comment: Which I already addressed in a comment here. You are comparing a `Role` with `String` which will obviously fail.

Comment: Yes - as I just said I know now it fails. But allow me to state again my problem; I cannot find a way to use Thymeleaf and iterate through a nested list. Dr. Google is not be forthcoming.