# With Thymeleaf, what's the syntax to find an item in a joined list using #lists.contains?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a table of Users joined to a table of Roles using ID. Users can have multiply IDs.I want to show a list of Users based on selected Roles. However I can only see all Roles that a User has. I cannot see if user.roles contains Admin or SuperAdmin.

On the users.html page I'm trying

```
<div>
    <ul th:each="user: ${users}">
         <li><span th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(user.roles)}">Has a Role</span></li>
         <li><span th:text="${user.roles}"> role </span></li>
         <li><span th:if="${#lists.contains(user.roles, 'ROLE_ADMIN')}">User admin</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This produces something like

- Has a Role
- [ROLE_DEFAULT_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
- 
- Has a Role
- [ROLE_DEFAULT_USER,  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DELEVOPER]
- 
- Has a Role
- [ROLE_DEFAULT_USER]
- 

I've tried th:if=*"${#lists.contains(#strings.toString(user.roles), 'ROLE_ADMIN')} .* But that only worked for the first instance of a User having a ROLE_ADMIN. Very odd.

Comment: Ofcourse not it is a `List<Role>` not a` LIst<String>` so the `contains` will not match.

Answer (score 0):

[solved] :-)

```
<div th:each="user : ${users}">
    <span th:text="${user.name}"> name </span>
    <div th:each="role : ${user.roles}">
        <div th:each="roles : ${role}">
            <li><span th:text="${role.name}"> role </span></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```